# 3 level of lists in nested view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have these tables `Pages`, `PageVersions` and `ElementsOnPageVersions`.

I want to show this on a page all at once, in a collapsible kind of view.

Like this:

- Page 1

  - Version 1
  - Version 2
  - Version 3
  - Version 4

    - Element 1
    - Element 2
    - Element 3
- Page 2

  - Version 1
  - Version 2
  - Version 3
  - Version 4

    - Element 1
    - Element 2
- Page 3

  - Version 1

    - Element 1
- Page 4

  - Version 1

    - Element 1

I'm uncertain on what the best way to retrieve the data and easily show it in the collapsaple layout is.

I would do something like this:

1. Get all items, all at once. "select * from ElementsOnPageVersion e inner join PageVersions v on e.PageVersion = v.id inner join Pages p on v.PageId = p.id"
2. Iterate through all, and build hierachical structure of sorted list to look like the collapsaple layout. PageLists[PagesObject], PagesObject has a sorted list of PageVersionObjects, which has a sorted list of ElementObjects.
3. Iterate through the final PagesList list Building the page. Inside this iterating through pageversionslist showing versions for the page, and Again inside every version iterating through elementslist.

This would be the way I would do it, at this moment. But it seems too heavy, and a lot of iterating.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: are you using entity framework ?

Comment: No. No entity framework.

Comment: where do you store the retrieved data ? in dataset ?

Comment: At the moment nowhere. I retrieve it, and hold it in a SqlDataReader. And there, iterate through it.

Comment: Is this webforms or mvc?

Answer (score 1):

I'd think about projecting your three different items to a single self-referencing list.  Each item would need an Id, Description, and ParentId.  I'd make a view model for this purpose.

```
public class TreeItem {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
}
```

That would allow for you to leverage either an asp:TreeView in webforms or whatever flavor of jQuery tree / treeview if you're using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

i actually built something that does something very similar. i can give you the HTML source to mine but i'd need to modify the .NET code to remove company specific, proprietary information before releasing that publicly (plus convert it to C#).

unfortunately for me to modify mine to your needs, it'd be almost up to one month before i'd be able to get around to it (due to a busy week before we take a 2 week vacation). but you can look at my HTML and see what you can reuse from it. from what i understand of your request, you'd be scratching about half of my JavaScript and its functionality. but if i were in your shoes, i'd appreciate this code to use as a starter and scrap what i didn't want and maybe add something. or you may just think my code is trash and not use it at all. ;P

so here's my HTML & JavaScript so you can run with it. It does handle the collapsing and expanding of nodes tho using ul and ol lists.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head><title>Oz-Med-Hist-VB</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=EmulateIE8' />
  <style type='text/css'>
    body { background: #CCC; margin-left: 1.5em; }
    li { list-style-type: none; text-indent: -38px; }

    .emptyGrayBox8 {
        background-color: #bbb; /* checked and unchecked background color */
        border: 1px solid #777; /* checked and unchecked border width & style & color */
        padding: 5.5px; display: inline-block; position: relative; margin: 0 3px; margin-top: 3px;
    }

    .checkInsideGrayBox:after {
        content: 'X';
        font-size: 13px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        left: 1.5px;
        color: #555;
    }

    .checkInsideGrayBoxInsideLI:after {
        content: 'X';
        font-size: 13px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        left: 39.5px;
        color: #555;
    }
  </style>
  <script>

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 8.') < 0)
    {
        document.write(
        '  <style>\n' +
        '   .checkInsideGrayBox               { left:  0.5px; }\n' +
        '   .checkInsideGrayBoxInsideLI:after { left: 38.5px; }\n' +
        '  </style>');
    }

var dta =
{   'checkedSubNodeCount--1'   : 0
,   'checkedSubNodeCount--19'  : 0
,   'checkedSubNodeCount--19-a': 0
,   'checkedSubNodeCount--19-b': 0
,   'checkedSubNodeCount--19-c': 0
,   'checkedSubNodeCount--22'  : 0
,   'checkedSubNodeCount--24'  : 0
,   'checkedSubNodeCount--25'  : 0
,   'checkedSubNodeCount--144' : 0
,   'checkedSubNodeCount--1728': 0
};

function chkBox_click(id) // this gets called when user clicks on checkbox or text to right of checkbox.
{ // when checkbox becomes checked, then associated group also becomes shown.
    var chkE = document.getElementById('chkBox--' + id); // CHecKBOX HTML element
    var grpE = document.getElementById('grpBox--' + id); // GRouPbox HTML element (UL element)
    var isChecked = chkE.checked;
    if (isChecked)
    {   // if user just checked the checkbox, and ...
        if (grpE != null) // if an associated (sub)group exists for this checkbox, ...
        { grpE.style.display = ''; } // then expand/show the group element.
    }
    setLabelHtm(id);
    var pid = getParentID(id); // Parent ID
    if (id == null) { return; } // if parent id doesn't exist then we're done here.

    // now 'pid' is parent ID of 'id'. for instance:
    // when id == '19-a'    then pid = '19'
    // when id == '19-a-1-' then pid = '19-a'

    var h = '';
    var maxLoopCount = 12; // infinite loop protection :P
    while (pid != null && --maxLoopCount >= 0)
    {
        chkE = document.getElementById('chkBox--' + pid); // CHecKBOX element *of parent*
        var pKey = 'checkedSubNodeCount--' + pid; // Key for this Parent ID
        if (isChecked) { ++dta[pKey]; } else { --dta[pKey]; }
        setLabelHtm(pid);
        if (h.length > 0) { h += '\n\n'; }
        h += 'id = ' + id + '   isChecked = ' + isChecked
        +   '\npid = ' + pid + '   chkE = ' + chkE
        +   '\ndta[\'' + pKey + '\'] = ' + dta[pKey];

        pid = getParentID(pid);
    }
//  alert(h);
} // function chkBox_click(id)

function chkBox_click8(id)
{
    var chkE = document.getElementById('chkBox--' + id); // CHecKBOX element
    var lblE = document.getElementById('chkLab--' + id); // CHecKbox LABel (HTML 'label' element for the checkbox)
    if (chkE == null || lblE == null) { return; }
    var isChecked = chkE.checked;
    var g = Number(chkE.tag);
    if (isChecked == false) { g = 3; chkE.tag = g; }
    if (isChecked == true ) { g = 2; chkE.tag = g; }
    alert(id + '\nisChecked = ' + isChecked + '\n.tag = ' + g);
} // function chkBox_click8(id)

function chkBox_clickIt(id)
{   var chkE = document.getElementById('chkBox--' + id); // CHecKBOX HTML element
    if (chkE != null) { chkE.click(); }
} // function chkBox_clickIt(id)

function getParentID(id)
{
    var pid = String(id); if (pid.length < 1) { return null; }
    if (pid[pid.length - 1] == '-') { pid = pid.substr(0, pid.length - 1); }
    var x = pid.lastIndexOf('-'); if (x < 0) { return null; }
    pid = pid.substr(0, x); // now pid is id of parent
    return pid;
} // function getParentID(id)

function hdrLab_click(id) // this will switch whether the associated group is hidden or shown
{// var chkE = document.getElementById('chkBox--' + id); // CHecKBOX HTML element
    var grpE = document.getElementById('grpBox--' + id); // GRouPBOX HTML element (UL element)
    if (grpE != null)
    {   if (grpE.style.display == '')
        {   grpE.style.display = 'none'; }
        else
        {   grpE.style.display = ''; }
    }
    setLabelHtm(id);
} // function hdrLab_click(id)

function setLabelHtm(id)
{   var grpE = document.getElementById('grpBox--' + id); // GRouPBOX HTML element (UL element)
    var lblE = document.getElementById('hdrLab--' + id);
    if (lblE == null) { return; }
    var h = null; var suffix = '.';
    if (grpE == null) { h = '<span style="visibility: hidden">+</span>'; }
    else
    {   var grpIsOpen = grpE.style.display == '';
        h = '<b>' + (grpIsOpen ? '−' : '+') + '</b>';
    }
    var s = String(id);
    if (s.length > 0 && s.substr(s.length - 1) == '-') { s = '&bull;'; suffix = ''; }
    else
    {
        var x = s.lastIndexOf('-') + 1;
        if (x > 0) { s = s.substr(x); }
    }
    h += '&nbsp;' + s + suffix;

    var cnt = dta['checkedSubNodeCount--' + id]; // CouNT of checked sub-nodes
    if (cnt != null) // if this node is a parent node
    {   var chkE = document.getElementById('chkBox--' + id); // CHecKBOX HTML element
        if (chkE != null) { chkE.style.display = (cnt > 0) ? 'none' : ''; }
        var hBeg = '<span class="emptyGrayBox8">';
        var hEnd = '</span>';
        if (cnt > 0) { h += hBeg + '<span class="checkInsideGrayBoxInsideLI"></span>' + hEnd; }
        else if (chkE == null) { h += hBeg + hEnd; }
    }
    lblE.innerHTML = h;
} // function setLabelHtm(id)

function init()
{   //alert('yes');
    hdrLab_click('1');
    hdrLab_click('1-a');
    hdrLab_click('19');
    hdrLab_click('19-a');
    hdrLab_click('19-a-1-');
    hdrLab_click('19-a-2-');
    hdrLab_click('19-b');
    hdrLab_click('19-b-1-');
    hdrLab_click('19-b-2-');
    hdrLab_click('19-b-3-');
    hdrLab_click('19-c');
    hdrLab_click('19-c-1-');
    hdrLab_click('19-c-2-');
    hdrLab_click('19-c-3-');
    hdrLab_click('22');
    hdrLab_click('22-a');
    hdrLab_click('22-b');
    hdrLab_click('23');
    hdrLab_click('24');
    hdrLab_click('24-a');
    hdrLab_click('24-b');
    hdrLab_click('24-c');
    hdrLab_click('25');
    hdrLab_click('25-a-');
    hdrLab_click('144');
    hdrLab_click('144-a');
    hdrLab_click('1728');
    hdrLab_click('1728-a');
//  alert(dta['checkedSubNodeCount--19-a']);
}
    window.onload = init;
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<ul style='list-style-type: none; margin-left: -1em'>
    <li><label id='hdrLab--1' onclick='hdrLab_click("1")' tabindex='0' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><label id='txtLab--1' onclick='hdrLab_click("1")')>&nbsp;Test for short number '1':</label></li>
    <ul id='grpBox--1'>
        <li><label id='hdrLab--1-a' onclick='hdrLab_click("1-a")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--1-a' onclick='chkBox_click("1-a");' /><label id='txtLab--1-a' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("1-a")')>Test for short number '1' subitem:</label></li>
    </ul>
    <li><label id='hdrLab--19' onclick='hdrLab_click("19")' tabindex='0' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><label id='txtLab--19' onclick='hdrLab_click("19")')>&nbsp;Which fruit do you prefer?</label></li>
    <ul id='grpBox--19'>
        <li><label id='hdrLab--19-a' onclick='hdrLab_click("19-a")' tabindex='0' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--19-a' onclick='chkBox_click("19-a");' /><label id='txtLab--19-a' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("19-a")')>Apples:</label></li>
        <ul id='grpBox--19-a'>
            <li><label id='hdrLab--19-a-1-' onclick='hdrLab_click("19-a-1-")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--19-a-1-' onclick='chkBox_click("19-a-1-");' /><label id='txtLab--19-a-1-' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("19-a-1-")')>Red delicious</label></li>
            <li><label id='hdrLab--19-a-2-' onclick='hdrLab_click("19-a-2-")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--19-a-2-' onclick='chkBox_click("19-a-2-");' /><label id='txtLab--19-a-2-' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("19-a-2-")')>Granny smith</label></li>
        </ul>
        <li><label id='hdrLab--19-b' onclick='hdrLab_click("19-b")' tabindex='0' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--19-b' onclick='chkBox_click("19-b");' /><label id='txtLab--19-b' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("19-b")')>Bananas:</label></li>
        <ul id='grpBox--19-b'>
            <li><label id='hdrLab--19-b-1-' onclick='hdrLab_click("19-b-1-")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--19-b-1-' onclick='chkBox_click("19-b-1-");' /><label id='txtLab--19-b-1-' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("19-b-1-")')>Green</label></li>
            <li><label id='hdrLab--19-b-2-' onclick='hdrLab_click("19-b-2-")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--19-b-2-' onclick='chkBox_click("19-b-2-");' /><label id='txtLab--19-b-2-' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("19-b-2-")')>Yellow (ripe but not too ripe)</label></li>
            <li><label id='hdrLab--19-b-3-' onclick='hdrLab_click("19-b-3-")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--19-b-3-' onclick='chkBox_click("19-b-3-");' /><label id='txtLab--19-b-3-' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("19-b-3-")')>Brown (<i>very</i> ripe)</label></li>
        </ul>
        <li><label id='hdrLab--19-c' onclick='hdrLab_click("19-c")' tabindex='0' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--19-c' onclick='chkBox_click("19-c");' /><label id='txtLab--19-c' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("19-c")')>Juice</label></li>
        <ul id='grpBox--19-c'>
            <li><label id='hdrLab--19-c-1-' onclick='hdrLab_click("19-c-1-")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--19-c-1-' onclick='chkBox_click("19-c-1-");' /><label id='txtLab--19-c-1-' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("19-c-1-")')>Orange juice</label></li>
            <li><label id='hdrLab--19-c-2-' onclick='hdrLab_click("19-c-2-")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--19-c-2-' onclick='chkBox_click("19-c-2-");' /><label id='txtLab--19-c-2-' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("19-c-2-")')>Grape juice</label></li>
            <li><label id='hdrLab--19-c-3-' onclick='hdrLab_click("19-c-3-")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--19-c-3-' onclick='chkBox_click("19-c-3-");' /><label id='txtLab--19-c-3-' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("19-c-3-")')>Tomato juice</label></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <li><label id='hdrLab--22' onclick='hdrLab_click("22")' tabindex='0' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><label id='txtLab--22' onclick='hdrLab_click("22")')>&nbsp;Which juice do you prefer?</label></li>
    <ul id='grpBox--22'>
        <li><label id='hdrLab--22-a' onclick='hdrLab_click("22-a")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--22-a' onclick='chkBox_click("22-a");' /><label id='txtLab--22-a' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("22-a")')>Apple juice</label></li>
        <li><label id='hdrLab--22-b' onclick='hdrLab_click("22-b")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--22-b' onclick='chkBox_click("22-b");' /><label id='txtLab--22-b' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("22-b")')>Orange juice</label></li>
    </ul>
    <li><label id='hdrLab--23' onclick='hdrLab_click("23")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--23' onclick='chkBox_click("23");' /><label id='txtLab--23' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("23")')>Single checkmark question with no subnodes</label></li>
    <li><label id='hdrLab--24' onclick='hdrLab_click("24")' tabindex='0' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><label id='txtLab--24' onclick='hdrLab_click("24")')>&nbsp;Best OS?</label></li>
    <ul id='grpBox--24'>
        <li><label id='hdrLab--24-a' onclick='hdrLab_click("24-a")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--24-a' onclick='chkBox_click("24-a");' /><label id='txtLab--24-a' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("24-a")') style='color:green'>Android!</label></li>
        <li><label id='hdrLab--24-b' onclick='hdrLab_click("24-b")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--24-b' onclick='chkBox_click("24-b");' /><label id='txtLab--24-b' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("24-b")') style='color:brown'>Apple</label></li>
        <li><label id='hdrLab--24-c' onclick='hdrLab_click("24-c")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--24-c' onclick='chkBox_click("24-c");' /><label id='txtLab--24-c' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("24-c")')>Linux</label></li>
    </ul>
    <li><label id='hdrLab--25' onclick='hdrLab_click("25")' tabindex='0' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--25' onclick='chkBox_click("25");' /><label id='txtLab--25' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("25")')>Check question with subnode check too.</label></li>
    <ul id='grpBox--25'>
        <li><label id='hdrLab--25-a-' onclick='hdrLab_click("25-a-")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--25-a-' onclick='chkBox_click("25-a-");' /><label id='txtLab--25-a-' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("25-a-")')>Sub-node check question</label></li>
    </ul>
    <li><label id='hdrLab--144' onclick='hdrLab_click("144")' tabindex='0' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><label id='txtLab--144' onclick='hdrLab_click("144")')>&nbsp;Test for 3-digit number:</label></li>
    <ul id='grpBox--144'>
        <li><label id='hdrLab--144-a' onclick='hdrLab_click("144-a")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--144-a' onclick='chkBox_click("144-a");' /><label id='txtLab--144-a' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("144-a")')>Test for 3-digit number subitem:</label></li>
    </ul>
    <li><label id='hdrLab--1728' onclick='hdrLab_click("1728")' tabindex='0' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><label id='txtLab--1728' onclick='hdrLab_click("1728")')>&nbsp;Test for 4-digit number:</label></li>
    <ul id='grpBox--1728'>
        <li><label id='hdrLab--1728-a' onclick='hdrLab_click("1728-a")' onkeypress='this.click(); return false;'></label><input type='checkbox' id='chkBox--1728-a' onclick='chkBox_click("1728-a");' /><label id='txtLab--1728-a' onclick='chkBox_clickIt("1728-a")')>Test for 4-digit number subitem:</label></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
<div style='display: none'>
<script>
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var ieVersion = null;
    var ix = 0;
    for (var v = 7; v <= 99; v++)
    {
        document.write('<!--[if IE ' + v + ']><hr />According to the conditional comment this is IE ' + v + '.<![endif]-->');
        if ((ix = ua.indexOf('MSIE ' + v + '.')) >= 0)
        {   ieVersion = '';
            ix += 5;
            while (ix < ua.length && '1234567890.'.indexOf(ua.charAt(ix)) >= 0)
            {   ieVersion += ua.charAt(ix++);
            }   document.write('<hr />According to JavaScript, this is IE ' + ieVersion);
        }
    }
    if (ieVersion == null)
    {   document.write('<hr />According to JavaScript, this IE version could not be determined.');
    }   document.write('<hr />navigator.userAgent = ' + navigator.userAgent);
</script><hr />
    <button id='webBtn1'>Fire an event</button>
    <button id='btnHi' onclick='window.external.sayHelloFromJavaScript("Hello from JavaScript!", 5);'>Say Hello</button>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

i also note that my project used a WebControl built for IE that needed to work as far back as WinXP. so i was limited in what i could use since it had to work for IE 7, but the nice thing is it works for way back to WinXP's latest working version of IE. i also care about using standards compliant code, so to my knowledge, my JavaScript also works for any standards-compliant browsers. i tested it in latest versions of Chrome and FF, and IE 10, IE 8 and IE 7.

there's still a good bit of code that's needed to generate the data into an HTML page, but this can solve half of your request.

in my .NET code, i had to build those JavaScript and HTML lists, which i can give in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dictionary objects to populate hierarchical data. This code sample might be helpful:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> dictPage = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string sPageID = row["PageName"].ToString();
    string sVersionID = row["VersionName"].ToString();
    string sElementID = row["ElementName"].ToString();

    if (!dictPage.ContainsKey(sPageID))
        dictPage.Add(sPageID, new Dictionary<string, List<string>>());

    if (!dictPage[sPageID].ContainsKey(sVersionID))
        dictPage[sPageID].Add(sVersionID, new List<string>());

    dictPage[sPageID][sVersionID].Add(sElementID);
}
```

I have used `DataTable` in this sample code, but you can use the same with `SqlDataReader`.

To create HTML you can do something like this:

```
StringBuilder sbHtmlUL = new StringBuilder();

sbHtmlUL.Append("<ul>");

foreach (var page in dictPage)
{
    sbHtmlUL.Append("<li>");
    sbHtmlUL.Append(page.Key);

    sbHtmlUL.Append("<ul>");

    foreach (var version in page.Value)
    {
        sbHtmlUL.Append("<li>");
        sbHtmlUL.Append(version.Key);

        sbHtmlUL.Append("<ul>");

        foreach (var element in version.Value)
        {
            sbHtmlUL.Append("<li>");
            sbHtmlUL.Append(element);
            sbHtmlUL.Append("</li>");
        }

        sbHtmlUL.Append("</ul>");
        sbHtmlUL.Append("</li>");
    }

    sbHtmlUL.Append("</ul>");
    sbHtmlUL.Append("</li>");
}

sbHtmlUL.Append("</ul>");
```

In this process, you can also apply CSS classes, IDs or simple JavaScript to add a collapse/expand behavior.

Please note that I did not compare performance of this code with other approaches so I am not so sure about it, but it took 8ms in a test, on an average machine, to process 8000 records.